# Facebook posting to news stream

Tags: php, facebook

I am aware how to post to a facebook news feed however what I wanted to do is post to the news stream on the top right side. For example, Spotify posts stories such as "x is listening to y"

does anyone know how this is achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create Open Graph stories, take a look at the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph